# selenium change firefox proxy to autoDetect c#

Tags: c#, selenium

I search to change the default proxy of firefox on firefoxDriver call.

I work in c#.

I know in java you do :

```
FirefoxProfile ff = new FirefoxProfile();
ff.setPreference("network.proxy.type", ProxyType.AUTODETECT.ordinal());
FirefoxDriver ffD = new FirefoxDriver(ff);
```

I tried :

```
FirefoxProfile ff = new FirefoxProfile();          
ff.SetPreference ("network.proxy.type",ProxyKind.AutoDetect.ToString ());
var driver = new FirefoxDriver(ff);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just forgot whats ordinal. After that.

```
ff.SetPreference ("network.proxy.type",(int)ProxyKind.AutoDetect);
```